# How do I feed a function containing a vector with different data types with these different data types?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am still struggling to realize what I want to do.
My code shall take user-defined segments (e.g. either a line, a circle, or whatever geometric segment definition I will implement) and chain them together in a vector. However, the order of segment type ("line", "circle",...) is user-defined and may hence vary from execution to execution.

Before I go on: Each segment has different input data needed for its own creation (e.g. a line has no radius, only starting and ending point).

My preferred approach would be to

1. read user input and identify order of segments
2. create each segment
3. Feed these to a function (e.g. member function/method for a class implementing the contour).
4. This function creates the contour, e.g. by implementing a vector.

My current test code has a hard-coded segment sequence but the trick that I want to achieve is that the order (and number) of segments is not hard-coded. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

class segment
{
public:
    segment() 
    {
        P1.x = 0;
        P1.y = 0;

        P2.x = 0;
        P2.y = 0;
    };
    virtual ~segment() {};

    virtual double get_radius() { return 0; };
    virtual double get_length() { return 0; };
    virtual double get_angle() { return 0; };

    int segment_id = 0;

protected:
    point P1;
    point P2;
};

class Line : public segment
{
public:
    Line() {};
    Line(const point pt1, const point pt2)
    {
        P1.x = pt1.x;
        P1.y = pt1.y;

        P2.x = pt2.x;
        P2.y = pt2.y;

        segment_id = 1;
    };

    ~Line() {};

    double get_length() { return calc_length(); };
    double get_angle() { return calc_angle(); };

private:
    double calc_length()
    {
        // calculate length (here: dummy value)
        return 1;
    }

    double calc_angle()
    {
        // calculate angle (here: dummy value)
        return 0.5;
    }

    double length = 0;
    double angle = 0;
}
;

class circle : public segment
{
public:
    circle()
    {
        center.x = 0;
        center.y = 0;
    };
    circle(const double r, const point c)
    {
        radius = r;
        center.x = c.x;
        center.y = c.y;

        segment_id = 2;
    };

    ~circle() {};

    double get_radius() { return radius; };
    point get_center() { return center; };
    double get_length() { return 3.14 * radius; }; //returns circumference

private:
    double radius = 0;
    point center;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int nbr = 5;
    point start;
    start.x = 1;
    start.y = 2;

    point end;
    end.x = 3;
    end.y = 4;

    point c;
    c.x = 0;
    c.y = 0;

    double r = 9;

    auto anotherCircle = std::make_unique<circle>(r, c);
    auto anotherLine = std::make_unique<Line>(start, end);

    std::unique_ptr<circle> yet_anotherCircle;

    circle* myCircle = new circle(r, c);
    Line* myLine = new Line(start, end);
    
    //VERSION 1: Does not compile. I get an exception in <memory> line 1762 when trying to delete _Ptr
    //std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v1;
    //v1.emplace_back(anotherCircle);
    //v1.emplace_back(anotherLine);
    //std::cout << v1[0]->get_radius() << std::endl;
    //v1.emplace_back(myLine);
    //std::cout << v1[1]->segment_id << std::endl;

    //VERSION 2: Compiles
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v2;

    v2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<circle>(r, c));

    v2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Line>(start, end));

}
```

The straight forward way that I imagine but that does not seem to work would require version 1 to work. I could then probably use template objects that I feed into the vector. Unfortunately this is not the way to go and I have not the slightest idea how to approach this. It would be awesome if somebody could help me here! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *move* items in vector, as your items are no copyable:

```
v1.emplace_back(std::move(anotherCircle));
```

Comment: Wow! THAT WORKS! THANK YOU! I struggled two days on this point and you solved it for me in less then five minutes. Unfortunately I can only upvote once.